# How to rewrite a PCRE regex searching for the subdomain to a Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre

How to transform this regex (searching for the subdomain)

```
http[s]?:\/\/(.*?)\..*\/
```

to JavaScript / ECMAScript regex?

I want to find the subdomain not the full line.
In PCRE, the brackets specify the part of the string I'm interested in, but in JavaScript, this doesn't seem to work.

https://regex101.com/r/xpO5Wc/1

[image]

vs

https://regex101.com/r/fQT1zC/2

[image]

Comment: The regex is flawed, but it works the same in PHP as in Javascript, there is no syntax to change

Comment: What is the problem with this regex in JS?

Comment: Have a look at this demo - https://regex101.com/r/fQT1zC/1

Comment: Actually i want to extract the subdomain not just find the line with subdomain. What's flawed?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `.*?`? The `*` already means "0 or more times", so it doesn't make sense to make it more optional. I assume from your description that you're not trying to match a literal `?`.

Comment: But also, your example 2 works! It's not highlighted in the same way in the main body of the page, but look at the panel on the right.

Comment: It's all just a matter of how regex101 presents the result. If you check the match information in the right pane they're the same.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the answer is that a rewrite is not really needed.
And it looks like just a display problem.

However in the interest of getting a better regex outcome, one
like this may give better results :

`/^http[s]?:\/\/(.*?)\.?([^\/.\r\n?]+\.[^\/.\r\n?]+)(?=\/|$)/mg`

https://regex101.com/r/JE1AHF/1

Group 1 gets the sub-subdomains
Group 2 gets the TLD and first subdomain.

Readable version:

```
 ^ 
 http s? ://
 ( .*? )                       # (1)
 \.? 
 ( [^/.\r\n?]+ \. [^/.\r\n?]+ )  # (2)
 (?= / | $ )
```